# how can I use the value from jsoup in java?

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to make an if statement with the information I got while web scrabing on yahoo finance in Android Studio using jsoup.

I get the value of bitcoin in my textview with the below code, however it's impossible for me to use the value of bitcoin in an "if statement". I tried to use `Integer.parseInt(quote.text())` and so on, but my app wont show anything, eventhough the "if" and "else" both show the value of bitcoin? I'm able to build the APK, but nothing happens when I press the button?

please note if you delete both the if statement and  `foo = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quote));` It will show the value of bitcoin on textview.

I want to display a text if the value of bitcoin is below or above 70000. Anyone have an idea?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView texx;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        texx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new doit().execute();
            }
        });
    }


    public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        String word;
        double a = 70000;
        double foo;


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            String url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD&.tsrc=fin-srch";

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element quote = doc.select("span[data-reactid='32']").first();

                foo = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quote));

                if(foo<a){
                    word = quote.text();
                }
                else{
                    word = quote.text();
                }






            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            texx.setText(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, if your app crashes you can edit your question and add the crash log, because no one can guess what error do you get.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Please see the updated code and question. Perhaps I wrote the question wrong, since I'm able to build the APK. However nothing shows when I press the button. If I delete Both: foo = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(quote));

            if(foo<a){
                word = quote.text();
            }
            else{
                word = quote.text();
            }.                                                                       and only show word = quote.text();
            } It prints the value og Bitcoin??

Comment: So you already know there's a problem with `parseDouble`. Try to guess why it's not working. The price I get is `59,057.88`. Try running only this line of code `Double.parseDouble("59,057.88");` and see the result. It doesn't have to be android, it's pure Java.